# jpa pagination suppress count query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

We are using Spring Data JPA Repository.
For pagination we are passing the Pageable object to the JPA Repository findBy Methods.

Since in our UI , we are not displaying the total count of records, we don't want the count query to be fired .
Is there any way to suppress the count query fired during pagination ?

Comment: Can you post your Repository or a sample?

Comment: But the total number is needed to calculate the number of pages. Or did you not have a next page button?

Comment: we are not dispalying the total number of pages . Next and Previous will be enabled in all pages. If there are no records after the last page, then we display a blank page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your repository method return `List<Entity>` rather than `Page<Entity>`, and I believe it won't run the count query.

See ["Special Parameter Handling" in Spring Data JPA documentation section "1.2.2 Defining query methods"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.special-parameters).

Comment: I was hoping it's possible to do this on a per-call basis. i.e. by making returned `Page` "lazy".

Comment: @HendyIrawan Why can't you just have two repository methods, one that returns Page and one that returns List?

Comment: yes I can and that's what I do, but the query is long and it means duplicating _exact_ query string. So yeah it's possible, but what I was really hoping _practically_ possible, not _workaroundy_ possible.